# How can I convert this line of erb into haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I'm still new to haml and was wondering how I could convert this line of code to work properly.  I'm using devise to get a signup page working.

```
<em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
```

When I left the code in erb the page worked fine but after trying to convert it to haml I get an error at this line.  I've tried the code below

```
%em
  = @minimum_password_length + (characters minimum)
```

But I get an error saying

```
undefined local variable or method `minimum'
```

When I try it without the parenthesis I get an error saying

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed Ruby between characters or inside a string, you can use string interpolation inside a text block:

```
%em
  | (#{@minimum_password_length} chars minimum)
```